# collection lock while inserting data in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

There are two VM's running in an environment and if any saveAll() request comes both do the operation at a time and I am ending up getting all the data twice. Is there any way we can lock the collection in mongodb when the first saveAll() is executing and the second one will check for any unique value and if it is present then it will not save the data to the collection. And meanwhile if any find query is fired it should continue working as it is.

I am using MongoDB shell version v4.2.3.

My query looks like- db.getCollection('Book').saveAll(books);

Answer (score 1):

The various options are described in [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).

A unique index sounds like a pretty good strategy: try to insert a value representing the batch being processed into a collection with a unique index, if this insert succeeds continue processing data, otherwise stop processing.